# Quick and dynamic way of assigning new properties into an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an empty object.

```
let obj = {};
```

Now I have some `if` conditions through which I want to assign new properties into my `obj` object

```
If(name = 'Alex) {
obj = {name: 'Alex'}
} else {
obj = {name: 'Bill'}
}
```

But it does not seem to work. I also used `Object.assign({}, name: 'Bill')` for example but it didn't work either. Do you know why is this happening and how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You are using `Object.assign` properly, Use it like `Object.assign(obj, {name: 'Bill'})` or simple `obj.name = "samething"`

Comment: wrong case for `if` and assignment instead of comparison.

Comment: `If(name = 'Alex) {` this is so wrong :) `*i*f (name *===* 'Alex*'* )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
let obj = {};
obj.name = name || 'Bill';
```

Your `if` condition is having one assignment like `name = 'Alex'` instead of comparison like `name === 'Alex'`. Fixing that will work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're *replacing* the object, not assigning to its properties. Here's how you do that:

```
obj.prop = value;
```

As an example, in your case:

```
obj.name = 'Alex';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems. `name= 'Alex'` is not correct syntax to compare things. `=`  assigns a value and not checks , should be `name == 'Alex'`.

Second, the correct syntax to assign a object property is

```
obj['name'] =  'Alex';
```

or even better `obj.name = 'Alex';`

So

```
if(name == 'Alex') {
   obj.name = 'Alex';
} else {
   obj.name = 'Bill';
}
```

Comment: The op specifically mentioned he/she wants to assign a value in the if condition.

Comment: @LajosArpad Nope. Based on if condition , op wants to assign a property.

Comment: I think you misunderstood "Now I have some if conditions through which I want to assign new properties into my obj object". Anyway, the If is incorrect as well. And it can be solved with assigning a value inside if and evaluating whether it is truey, like if (!(name = 'Alex')) {obj.name = 'Bill';}

Comment: @LajosArpad Sorry I have not misunderstood and you can check the same solution with other answers here aswell. Assigning inside if condition doesnt make sense at all to me

Comment: I have to down-vote your answer at least until you correct your If to if...

Comment: @LajosArpad just corrected. Copy pasted it from OP and never looked at it. Thanks for pointing though

Comment: No problem, down-vote was undone. I still disagree with you about the question, but I think your answer is good if you are right about the question. If the op confirms that, then it even deserves an upvote

Comment: @LajosArpad I may wrong. But this is what I have understood from OP's posted code.

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1. You are using a capital I instead of a lower-case i when you write `If` instead of `if`
2. You assign `'Alex` to a variable called `name`, which does not exist. You need to assign it to `obj.name`.
3. You do not close `'Alex`, you need to close it like `'Alex'`
4. You recreate the object which was already created, so you do not assign new properties to your object, but you create a new object instead with some properties.

Possible solutions:

1. Closest to your code:

   `if(!(obj.name = 'Alex)) {
       obj.name = 'Bill'; //We assign 'Alex' as name and if it is falsey, then override it with 'Bill'
   }`
2. Shortest:

   `obj.name = 'Alex' || 'Bill'`;

which will assign `'Alex'` to `obj.name` if `'Alex'` is truey and `'Bill'` otherwise.

3. Very explicit:

   `if ('Alex') {
       obj.name = 'Alex';
   } else {
       obj.name = 'Bill';
   }`

You can pick the one which is closest to your taste, however, note that `'Alex'` will always be truey.